# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got "(" at

Tags: google-bigquery, data-analysis

Here's what I am trying to run in BigQuery, but keep getting error code. What am I doing wrong?

#Show number of deaths of is person was smoker

```
select dea.location, dea.population, gen.female_smokers, gen.male_smokers
sum(female_smokers) as TotalFemales, sum(gen.male_smokers) as TotalMale over (PARTITION BY dea.location order by dea.location, dea.population) as RollingWomen
FROM capstone-project-317016.Portfolio1.CovidDeaths dea;
join capstone-project-317016.Portfolio1.CovidbyGender gen
on dea.location = gen.location
and dea.population = gen.population
where dea.location is not null
group by dea.population
```

Comment: add comma after `gen.male_smokers` to experience more errors. it is quite a mess so you should work through code piece by piece before posting such !!!

Comment: I dont understand your response... I am a new DA and practicing on my own hence my seeking help. Now I get another error: Syntax error: OVER keyword must follow a function call at [2:73]

Comment: before posting such questions  - we expect you to do some [at least] minimal research efforts! so you don't treat us as a search engine which minimizes chances for you to get helped :o)

Comment: I received another error: Syntax error: OVER keyword must follow a function call

Answer (score 0):

Add comma after gen.male_smokers line 1

There must be some aggregate function before over (PARTITION BY dea.location order by dea.location, dea.population) as RollingWomen